# Displaying determinant nxn using dynamic allocation

Tags: c

my c program gets the matrix from the user but i can't get the
minor(determinant) function to work.

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int** minor(int** a, int n, int i, int j) {
    int k;
   
    a = (int**)realloc(n - 1, sizeof(int*));
    if (a == NULL)
    {
        printf("Error! memory not allocated.");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    for (k = 0; k < n - 1; k++)
    {
        *(a + k) = (int*)realloc(n - 1, sizeof(int));
        if (*(a + k) == NULL)
        {
            printf("Error! memory not allocated.");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
    }

    for (k = i; k < n - 1; k++)
    {
        for (int t = 0; t < n - 1; t++)
        {
            a = (a + k) + t;
        }
    }
    return a;
}


int main()
{
    int i, j, n, **a;

    printf("Enter size of a: \n");
    scanf("%d", &n);

    a = (int**)malloc(n * sizeof(int*));
    if (a == NULL)
    {
        printf("Error! memory not allocated.");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        *(a + i) = (int*)malloc(n * sizeof(int));
        if (*(a + i) == NULL)
        {
            printf("Error! memory not allocated.");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
    }

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < n; j++)
        {
            printf("Enter A[%d][%d]: ", i, j);
            scanf("%d", *(a + i) + j);
        }
    }

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < n; j++)
        {
            printf("%d ", *(*(a+i)+j));
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

    printf("Enter i:\n");
    scanf("%d", &i);
    printf("Enter j: \n");
    scanf("%d", &j);

    printf("You entered: i=%d, j=%d\n", i, j);

    for (i = 0; i < n - 1; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < n - 1; j++)
        {
            printf("%d ", minor(a, n, i, j));
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
   
    free(a);
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        free(a + i);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: <O/T> `free(a);` must go _after_ your loop where you `free(a + i);`

Comment: `minor` returns an `int**`, the `"%d"` format specifier `printf` expects an `int`, you should be getting a warning about this.

Comment: `realloc(n - 1,..` The first argument of `realloc` should be a pointer, you're giving it an `int`.

Comment: Error belong on stderr. `fprintf(stderr, "Error! memory not allocated.");`. Even better, to allow the user's locale to provide a language specific error message, you could do `perror("malloc");`